# LinkedList does not provide index based access, so why does it have get(index) method?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I understand that ArrayList is index based datastructure, that allows you to access its element using the index but LinkedList is not supposed index based so why does it have get(index) method that allows direct access to the element?

Comment: The question is a bit incorrect, I think, because getIndex(i) is not an interface of linked list, it's an interface of dictionary data structure, which in turn may be implemented by means of linked list

Comment: What do you mean by "index based datastructure"?

Comment: Dictionary data structure is a data structure, values of which are accessed by means of their keys. Particularly in Lists, keys are indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really just an implementation decision. While an array would probably be a fairly useless data structure if you can't look up elements by index, adding a by-index lookup to a linked-list implementation doesn't do any harm (well, unless users assume it's fast - see below), and it does come in handy sometimes.

One can assign every element a number as follows:

```
      0               1           2           3           4
Head (Element0) -> Element1 -> Element2 -> Element3 -> Element4 -> NULL
```

From here, it's trivial to write a function to return the element at some given index.

Note that a by-index lookup on a linked-list will be slow - if you're looking for let's say the element in the middle, you'll need to work through half the list to get there.

Answer (score 6):

It may not be efficient to retrieve items from a linked list by index, but linked lists do have indices, and sometimes you just need to retrieve an item at a certain index. When that happens, it's much better to have a `get` method than to force users to grab an iterator and iterate to the desired position. As long as you don't call it too much or the list is small, it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers imply that LinkedLists have indices.

However, a fixed index for every element in the data structure would defeat the purpose of the LinkedList and e.g. make some remove/add operations slower because the structure would need to be reindexed every time. This would take linear time, even for elements at the beginning and at the end of the list, that are crucial for Java's LinkedList's efficiency.

From [Java's LinkedList implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l564) you can see that there is no constant time index access to the element, but rather a linear traversal where the exact element is figured out on the go.